# Tagging a process so I can kill it later easily by identifying

Tags: process, kill, pkill

I need to tag a generic process (I don't really control the command being run).

Could I do something like this:

```
run_special_cmd(){
   "$@"  -- --very-special-command
}

run_special_cmd sleep 5000 && echo 'bar'
```

and then later use:

```
pkill -9 -f '--very-special-command'
```

to id those processes to be killed? Or is there a better generic way to tag procs for later identification?

Comment: Put something in its environment. Or use `special_command& special_pid=$!; ...; kill $special_pid`.

Answer (score 3):

Not all command would ignore arbitrary arguments that you pass them.

If the called process doesn't fork, you can save the pid of the calling process and call it with exec. Use a script

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $$ > /var/run/foo.pid
exec "$@"
```

This will execute the command in the same process, with the pid saved before the process was executed.

If you want the pid file removed, you can delete it after the process exits.

```
#!/bin/bash
PIDFILE=/var/run/foo.pid
"$@" &
echo $! > $PIDFILE
wait
rm -f $PIDFILE
```

This will start the process in the background, record the pid, wait for the process to exit and then remove the file.

Comment: yeah i really need to tag processes by name instead of pid, otherwise pids could be stale or the wrong pid, since pids can be reused.

Comment: A added a way to remove the file after the process exits.